# Holux GPS logger .itm fileformat

Tags: gps

I'm looking for a spec sheet or a library to open and decompress .itm files from the [Holux GPS logger](https://www.holuxdevice.com/gps-receiver.html).

Has anyone worked with the proprietary .itm format already and can provide me with some useful information?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late answer, but i was looking for the same for last 2 years. Finally, i think i found something interesting, even if it's not a `*.itm` file specification.
Seems `*.itm` file is a SqlLite database and it can be convertet into `*.gpx` file (xml). I've been able to successfully use [itmtogpx](https://code.google.com/archive/p/itmtogpx/downloads) application.

Depending on holux gps model there's a free [software](http://market.holux.com/Software/SU/), which you can download and use to visualize `*.itm` data.

In my opinion, an `*.itm` file is generated from `*.poi` and `*.itx` files, because the weigth of `*.itm` file is very similar to sum of both: `*.itm` and `*.itx` files.